# Xamarin Test Cloud file upload

Tags: file-upload, xamarin-test-cloud

I am running tests on Xamarin Test Cloud, where I am unable to Upload the images or files in script that I have written. The script gets stuck at a statement `app.Tap(x => x.Text("Attach Image"))`. Where button event is clicked and options are given to upload the file from the gallery or camera...

```
app.Tap(x => x.Class("FormsImageView").Index(3));
// app.Repl();
app.Tap(x => x.Text("Loews Chicago O'Hare"));
//app.Tap(x => x.Text("Attach Image"));
//app.Tap(x => x.Text("Open Gallery"));
//app.Tap(x => x.Id("text1"));
app.Tap(x => x.Class("EditorEditText"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your approach correctly, then the problem is likely two-fold:

1. **Xamarin.UITest cannot automate system apps like the Gallery or Camera**. In order to run tests dependent on features of the system apps, the behavior has to actually be integrated into your app itself, so that it doesn't require launching a separate app; or you have to employ backdoor methods to simulate the behavior for your tests.
2. **You might not be including the files so that Xamarin.UITest can access them**. Files your app needs to run tests must either be included as an embedded resource or uploaded using the `--data` optional flag in the command line.

More information:

- Backdoors guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/
- Generic backdoors sample: https://github.com/King-of-Spades/BackdoorExample/tree/master
- Information on uploading data along with your app: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/189113/#Comment_189113